# Autorefresh function passing id from Url

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to have autorefresh function while passing id from the URL

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval( this.props.fetchId({ id: this.props.match.params.id }), 15000)
    this.props.fetchId({ id: this.props.match.params.id })
  }
```

Implementation of fetchId in actions/index.js

```
  export const FETCH_ID = 'fetch_id'
  export const fetchId = (params) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
  const res = await api.get('/api/records/' + params.id)
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ID,
    payload: { id: params.id, data: res.data }
  })
}
```

I tried with above code ,it works fine with initial load but after the component is rendered ,this.props.match.params.id is getting undefined and getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: `setInterval`'s first parameter expects a function, `fetchId` most likely, isnt. Could you show us part of the implementation of `fetchId`?

Comment: @Caramiriel I have edited the post with fetchId implementation.Please check it

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this question,I was invoking function instead of calling it.When I called the function like below, auto refresh started working as expected

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval( () => this.props.fetchId({ id: this.props.match.params.id }), 15000)
    this.props.fetchId({ id: this.props.match.params.id })
  }
```